# Unable to generate Serenity aggregate report when tests are executed through Junit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I see that for each test execution individual html report is getting generated ,but aggregated(combined) report is not getting generated. Is there a configuration that I need for it?

If I run the below command, it generates the aggregate report for me combining the individual reports, but just wondering why isn't it generated after the tests finish execution.

```
mvn serenity:aggregate -Dserenity.outputDirectory=C:/PoC-Test/target/site/serenity
```

Following is my **POM** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.serenitybdd.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Serenity project with JUnit and WebDriver</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>1.8.3</serenity.version>
        <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray-plugins</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.5</version>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/When*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Story.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tags>${tags}</tags>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation is a separate function that is only run (intentionally) once all the tests are finished.

Comment: Thanks John. Does that mean that the reports are generated individually for each test only until this aggregation function is run? I thought that a combined report is generated for all the tests with `post-integration-test`. Isn't that true?

Answer (score 1):

I do run `mvn serenity:aggregate` explicitly after JUnit executes all tests. This will aggregate all results and form index.html report file in your `./target/site/serenity` folder. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if the aggregate report should be generated by default.

Comment: I think I got your questions. you can do something like this. Though I haven't tested it. Have a check yourself: `public class TestSuite {
 @After
 public void after() throws IOException {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c mvn serenity:aggregate");
 }
}`

Comment: Here the @After (Assuming you are using JUnit) method will be executed once all the features are executed. Once done, just run the command.